# PortableApps.com application Prompts to update even after updating the firefox portable?

Tags: firefox, portable-applications

Every time *PortableApps.com* checks for the update Even if you update the application (Ex. Firefox) inside the application settings (Help->About).

How can we avoid this since I am already updated the application?

[image: PortableApp.com and Firefox]

Comment: This question is interesting, but I am affraid offtopic here.

Comment: @AlKepp: I don't think its off-topic, you can find many questions like this [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firefox+portable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=firefox+portable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*PortableApps.com* application have the product version inside the respective config file which is not changing automatically while the application (Ex. Firefox) is update itself.

Another thing is if you are updating from Firefox 35.0 to 35.0.1 then the update only needs 3 MB but if you are using the above app then you have to download the entire Firefox app (41 MB) from internet. It is annoying rite?

To avoid this change the config file manually as mentioned below.

1. Go to *PortableApps\FirefoxPortable\App\AppInfo*
2. Open "appinfo.ini" file
3. Move to version section and see the PackageVersion (35.0.0.0)
4. This should be changed to 35.0.1.0

Thats all. Next time you will not be prompted to update the Firefox.

Note : You may use the same technique across the other *PortableApps.com* applications.